# Given $X,Y$ sets, then $\exists Z \text{ s.t. } Z \cong X \text{ and } Z \cap Y = \varnothing$

Tags: proof-verification, set-theory

I want to prove, in ZF, the following statement

> Given two non empty sets $X$ and $Y$, there exists a set $Z$ s.t. $$Z \cong X \text{ and } Z \cap Y = \varnothing$$

This is the sketch of my try:

- I define a formula $\varphi(x,z,X,Y)$: $$\varphi(x,z,X,Y) = (Y \in z) \wedge (x \in z) \wedge \forall a(a\in z \Rightarrow a = Y \vee a = x)$$
  which embodies a functional relation:
  \begin{align*} 
  \varphi: X &\longrightarrow  V \\ 
  x &\longmapsto  \{Y,x\}
  \end{align*}
- I apply the Axiom of Replacement and get a set $Z$ which is the image of $\varphi$. Then through various axioms (in particular specification) I get the existance of a function $\varphi:X \rightarrow Z$ which behaves exactly as the functional relation.
- $\varphi$ is a bijection, therefore $X \cong Z$
- By foundation I have that $Z \cap Y = \varnothing$, in fact otherwise I'd have a $y \in Y$ s.t. $Y \in y$ and this would violate the non existence of an infinite descending sequence of sets.

Is this correct? Is there a more straightforward way to show this? Thanks

Comment: Try to find an argument that avoids foundation. Rather than using $Y$ in the sets $\{Y,x\}$ all you need is to ensure that there is some set you can put there.

Comment: For instance, show that there is a set not in $\{a:\{a,x\}\in Y$ for some $x\in X\}$.

Comment: Ok, but it seems to me that in order to prove the existence of such set I still need foundation...

Comment: In general, given a set $X$, the proof of the existence of a set $a$ not in $X$ uses foundation, right?

Comment: No, this is easier. Remember Russell's paradox.

Comment: right, right. Thanks

Comment: Note that the non-empty hypothesis on $X$ and $Y$ is unnecessary. If $X = \emptyset$ or $Y = \emptyset$ (or both), we can just take $Z = X$, and $Z\cap Y = \emptyset$ is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just implementing the sketch in the original post, with the argument suggested in the comments that avoids invoking foundation:

First, for any set $A$ there is a set $a\notin A$. This follows from the argument for Russell's paradox (there is no set of all sets, or by separation there would be a set of all sets that do not belong to themselves) or Cantor's theorem (that no map from a set to its power set is surjective).

Now, for any $a,b$ and any set $A$, if $\{a,b\}\in A$ then $a\in \bigcup A$. It follows that $Y'=\{a:\exists x\in X\,(\{a,x\}\in Y)\}$ is a set, by separation and union, and therefore there is a set $b\notin Y'$. But then $Z=\{\{b,x\}:x\in X\}$ is a set in bijection with $X$, by the argument in the original post, and it is disjoint from $Y$ by our choice of $b$.